# How can I compare a current version of file to an older version in SmartGit

Tags: smartgit

I was trying to find where a bug was introduced into my code, so I wanted to compare my current file to the last version of the file I knew to be good.

I found out I could see a list of commits that contained that file by viewing the file's log, but how can I see all those changes combined up to a certain point?

In other words, how can I compare a current version of a file to a single specific version of that file a couple commits ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select both commits in the **Commits** graph, this will display all modifications in the **Files** view. Now select the file which is interesting for you there (SmartGit should have it preselected) and you will see the diff in the **Changes** view.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot. Any idea how I can do the same for a modified working copy that has not been committed? I.e. how can I compare a single file in my working copy to the version of a random commit? When trying your way, there actually is a "Working copy" in the Graph, but selecting it along a random Commit empties all other views. (feels like a bug to me)